# Keep duplicate entries where I use group_by() from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

```
library(dplyr) ##activates the data.table library

mydataWithWeeksAndWeights <- data_frame(ended = c("14/11/2016",
                                                  "14/11/2016",
                                                  "14/11/2016",
                                                  "02/01/2017",
                                                  "02/01/2017",
                                                  "15/11/2017",
                                                  "15/11/2017",
                                                  "16/11/2017",
                                                  "16/11/2017"),
                                        week = c(46, 46, 46, 1, 1, 46, 46, 46, 46),
                                        satisfactionLevel = c("Very dissatisfied",
                                                              "Very satisfied",
                                                              "Satisfied",
                                                              "Dissatisfied",
                                                              "Very dissatisfied",
                                                              "Very satisfied",
                                                              "Very dissatisfied",
                                                              "Very Satisfied",
                                                              "Very satisfied"),
                                        weight = c(0, 1, 0.75, 0.25, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1))
```

When I call the following function `pivotTable <- mydataWithWeeksAndWeights %>% group_by(week, weight) %>% count(satisfactionLevel)` it counts the satisfactionLevel for all week 46 entries. The problem is that the 46th week for the first three rows refers to 2016 with the remaining referring to 2017. I want to keep these duplicate entries.

Comment: Try `mydataWithWeeksAndWeights %>% group_by(week, weight) %>% filter(n()>1)`

Comment: I guess you want to distinguish between the years. You could do this using `df %>% group_by(year_week = format(as.Date(ended, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%W"), weight) %>% count(satisfactionLevel)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Legendary!!! Cheers

Comment: @docendodiscimus can you please submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Greconomist it's already implemented in the existing answer in similar fashion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be sure that my code does what you want as you don't give an expected output, but I think what you need to do is add a `year` column and add it to the `group_by` so that you differentiate between week 46 of 2016 and week 46 of 2017.

Edit: in case you need to automatically define the year from the end-date that you have, I'm adding in the bit in @docendodiscimus's comment:

```
library(dplyr)

mydataWithWeeksAndWeights <- data_frame(ended = c("14/11/2016",
                                                  "14/11/2016",
                                                  "14/11/2016",
                                                  "02/01/2017",
                                                  "02/01/2017",
                                                  "15/11/2017",
                                                  "15/11/2017",
                                                  "16/11/2017",
                                                  "16/11/2017"),
                                        week = c(46, 46, 46, 1, 1, 46, 46, 46, 46),
                                        satisfactionLevel = c("Very dissatisfied",
                                                              "Very satisfied",
                                                              "Satisfied",
                                                              "Dissatisfied",
                                                              "Very dissatisfied",
                                                              "Very satisfied",
                                                              "Very dissatisfied",
                                                              "Very Satisfied",
                                                              "Very satisfied"),
                                        weight = c(0, 1, 0.75, 0.25, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1))

mydataWithWeeksAndWeights$year <- format(as.Date(mydataWithWeeksAndWeights$ended,
                                                 "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y")

pivotTable <- mydataWithWeeksAndWeights %>%
  group_by(week, year, weight) %>%
  count(satisfactionLevel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do: reformat "ended" to a Date Format and use aggregate function:

```
# just to shorten df-name
df <- mydataWithWeeksAndWeights 

# reformat and add column with year
df[,"ended"] <- as.Date(df[[1]], format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df$year <- format(df[[1]], "%Y")

# actual aggregating
aggregate (df$weight, by = list(df$year, df$satisfactionLevel, df$week), FUN = sum)
```

Hope this helps!